# Reading one double quotation mark in string field from txt file

Tags: r

I'm pulling from a tab deliminated txt file, where a string field has been reduced. Occasionally this field will have a single double quotation mark, but not the second quotation mark.

txt file example:

```
Q1
Check "QC
Something Else
Check "AC
```

Currently my code is:

```
all_content = readLines("File.txt")
read.csv(textConnection(all_content), sep = "\t", header=TRUE)

#all_content gives: [1] "Q1"             "Check \"QC"     "Something Else" "Check \"AC"
```

which gives:

```
  Q1
1 Check QC\nSomething Else\nCheck AC
```

Adding quote = "\"" gives the same output. My quick solution at the moment is to just remove all quotation marks but I'd like another solution if possible.

I can have the person encoding the file do something different as well if that would resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and it should read three lines (rows) of data:

```
df <- read.csv('input.csv', quote = NULL)
```

Output:

```
              Q1
1      Check "QC
2 Something Else
3      Check "AC
```